# Game Center not dismissing?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-center, dismiss, spritebuilder

Im trying to dismiss Game Center when the user is pressing Done, why is this not working?? I've looked at the Apple docs and Googled it ever way I can think of, what is wrong?

**GCHelper.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

@protocol GameCenterManagerDelegate

@end

@interface GCHelper : NSObject <GKGameCenterControllerDelegate, GKAchievementViewControllerDelegate, GKLeaderboardViewControllerDelegate> {

BOOL gameCenterAvailable;
BOOL userAuthenticated;

UIViewController *presentingViewController;
id <GameCenterManagerDelegate> delegate;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong)  id <GameCenterManagerDelegate> delegate;
@property (assign, readonly) BOOL gameCenterAvailable;
@property (retain) UIViewController *presentingViewController;

+ (GCHelper *) showGameCenter;
+ (GCHelper *)sharedInstance;
- (void)authenticateLocalUser;

@end
```

**GCHelper.m**

```
#import "GCHelper.h"

@implementation GCHelper

@synthesize gameCenterAvailable;
@synthesize presentingViewController;
@synthesize delegate;


#pragma mark Initialization

static GCHelper *sharedHelper = nil;
static GCHelper *showGameCenter = nil;

+ (GCHelper *) sharedInstance {
if (!sharedHelper) {
    sharedHelper = [[GCHelper alloc] init];
}
return sharedHelper;
}

- (BOOL)isGameCenterAvailable {
// check for presence of GKLocalPlayer API
Class gcClass = (NSClassFromString(@"GKLocalPlayer"));

// check if the device is running iOS 4.1 or later
NSString *reqSysVer = @"4.1";
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
BOOL osVersionSupported = ([currSysVer compare:reqSysVer
                                       options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending);

return (gcClass && osVersionSupported);
}

- (id)init {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    gameCenterAvailable = [self isGameCenterAvailable];
    if (gameCenterAvailable) {
        NSNotificationCenter *nc =
        [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [nc addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(authenticationChanged)
                   name:GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName
                 object:nil];
    }
}
return self;
}

- (void)authenticationChanged {

if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated && !userAuthenticated) {
    NSLog(@"Authentication changed: player authenticated.");
    userAuthenticated = TRUE;
} else if (![GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated && userAuthenticated) {
    NSLog(@"Authentication changed: player not authenticated");
    userAuthenticated = FALSE;
}

}

#pragma mark User functions

- (void)authenticateLocalUser {

if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;

NSLog(@"Authenticating local user...");
if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].authenticated == NO) {
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:nil];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Already authenticated!");
}
}


/*
- (void) showBanner

{

NSString* title = [self generateTitle];

NSString* message = [self generateBannerMessage];

[GKNotificationBanner showBannerWithTitle: title message: message

                        completionHandler:^{

                            [self advanceToNextInterfaceScreen]

                        }];

}
*/

+ (GCHelper *)showGameCenter
{
@synchronized (self)
{
GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];

if (gameCenterController != NULL)

{

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
}
return showGameCenter;
}

// When player dismisses game center.
- (void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController

{

gameCenterViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
[gameCenterViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the director that needs to be dismissed, but the `GKGameCenterViewController` that you receive by parameter in the function `-(void)gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish`. You should do this :

```
- (void) gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish:(GKGameCenterViewController *)gameCenterViewController{
    [gameCenterViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**EDIT** : You also have to set the delegate of your controller to your current scene and implement `<GKGameCenterControllerDelegate>` in the .h file of your class :

```
//In your .h file
@interface foo : CCScene <GKGameCenterControllerDelegate>{
}

//In you .m file
GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController alloc] init];

if (gameCenterController != NULL)
{
    gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector]presentViewController:gameCenterController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: You have to set the `delegate` property of your view controller to your current scene. Check back my updated answer for the full code!

Comment: this is the error I get when doing that. 'incompatible pointer types assigning to 'id<GKGameCenterControllerDelegate>' from 'Class'

Comment: Are you assigning the `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` protocol to your class in your .h file? I suppose your class is a CCScene?

Comment: I did this as well: implement <GKGameCenterControllerDelegate> in the .h file in my GCHelper class : thats a subclass of NSObject.

Comment: Try putting `gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;` in your `showGameCenter` function instead of in `gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish`. The delegate tells to the viewController which of your Object will control and implement functions to dismiss your view.

Comment: I did, that's when I get the warning: 'incompatible pointer types assigning to 'id<GKGameCenterControllerDelegate>' from 'Class'

Comment: I think you are getting this error because your `showGameCenter` is a Class function (+) instead of an Instance(-) function. Try putting it a Instance function, remove @synchronized(self) and call your function by doing `[[GCHelper sharedHelper] showGameCenter];`. Your gameCenterDelegate can't receive a class, but an instance of that class, that's why you must use the (-) instead of (+). You should take a look at this (https://github.com/ablfx/ABGameKitHelper) GameCenter helper, which is the one I am using right now. Look for the `showLeaderBoard` function

Comment: If I do that(-), which I tried doing before the (+)method I get these errors on :[[GCHelper sharedHelper] showGameCenter];
no known class method for selector 'sharedHelper'
no known instance method for selector 'showGameCenter'

Comment: Oops my bad, your selector is called sharedInstance, and not sharedHelper. And you did changed the + from `showGameCenter` in your .h file, right? Those two errors are only because XCode can't find your selectors, so either you misspelled it when calling them or when creating them. It also depends on where you are calling [[GCHelper sharedInstance] showGameCenter], if you are calling it from a (-) function within your class, you can only use [self showGameCenter]

Comment: Genius! lol I was commenting it out in the .h file...geez I change to -(void) in .h and .m working now! Thank you for your patients on this!!

Comment: My pleasure, we did it! :)